# National characters list

Tags: perl, unicode, internationalization, character, letters

How (or where) to get the national letters user by states/nationalities? E.g.: for example the:

- Gernan language uses `öäüß` (plus ascii letters)
- Hungarian: `áéíóöúüőű`
- Czech: `áéíóúýčďěňřšťůž`
- Iceland: `áæéíðóöúýþ`

etc..

Tagged as perl because using it for scripting, but any idea and/or reference is welcomed.

- The locale definitions file for `LC_CTYPE` doesn't helps, because it is only an link to common `utf8-C_TYPE` used by all languages
- the `\p{Latin}` covers all characters from the extended latin block, so not for the given country.
- the above examples are done by removing Ascii from some Pangrams what i found on the web.
- Is possible done this somewhat correctly by (perl) script, or the only way is searching the web for some "documents" which describes the "official" alphabet for the given country?

Comment: I don't think any such list will ever be accurate. For example, let's use English. Is it A-Z? Or are there more? Take resumé or naïve. These are words used in the English language, though if one were to ask, "what characters are used in English" I don't think people would list the accented characters. We live in an internationalized world where languages steal words from each other all the time.

Comment: @dman2306 you're right, but for each country _exists_ an "official" alphabet definition and wondering about how to get the somewhat by script. (e.g. some collation definitios or such, for example the Icelandic `þ` sure should be sorted at end of the hungarian `z`... or something like..

Comment: @jm666, I've never heard of the concept of countries having official alphabets before. I seriously doubt every country has one. I wouldn't be surprise if no country has one. Official language? Surely every country has one (if only de-facto), but alphabet???

Comment: Like you say, definitely de-facto even on the language. The United States has no official language. But, now that I understand the question is relating to collation, not something like saying "you can't use characters outside of this alphabet" I know it does exist. I can't speak to Perl, but I know Windows includes this information because I use it all the time to sort strings in SQL Server based on a particular collation. For example, I know to get the info you want for German is German_PhoneBook_CI_AS. The bigger question is how does one extract it from the OS...

Comment: Use [The Unicode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode::Collate)

Comment: Don't extract it from the OS. Let the OS handle it in the first place.

Comment: OS locales are notorious for being broken. At the very least, that means it's not a good way to go if you want portability.

Comment: Just a side note: This task isn't as easy as you think it might be, there are often special cases: In German, for example, we use the é in "Café" (for the place you go to) and I think you might find examples like these in many languages.

Comment: What task are you trying to accomplish with these character lists? (As an aside, the list for languages like Chinese and Japanese would contain thousands of characters.)

Comment: The most important thing is to know what problem is being solved (the primary problem is probably *not* finding out what letters constitute the official alphabet of each country).  Once we know what problem is being solved, we might have a solution that doesn't have to deal with the dubious notion of national alphabets.

Comment: The PRIMARY problem is finding the national characters. Not collation, it was only an example. I was wondered about the possibility - extract them from some CPAN module. Probably doesn't exist such collection - so will delete the question. About the comments. If you search the web for "pangram" - each author perfectly knows, what characters belongs to his language. I know exactly for cs,hu,sk. Probably the best what i could do, is manually collect the "pangrams" from the web and remove the "ascii" part. (need only the latin ones). Thanks for the comments anyway. :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924#List_of_codes

Comment: Take a look here, http://nordendivision.nfi.ku.dk/about_ungegn/romanization/Leira%20Vigleik%20_2008_%20Alphabets%20Letters%20and%20Diacritics%20in%20European%20Languages.pdf - good overview and probably contains what you want.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. of course, when you searching for the examples of the "exceptions", you're right. But you probably won't want to to say than the 'é' is an common german character what belongs to the german "alphabet" - e.g. what is commonly used to write the german words (not foreign words). Why everybody nitpicking on the exceptions and not to try answer with an "common base" e.g. what allows answer the "spirit" of the question? (and it sure isn't a list of the exceptions)...

Answer (score 2):

Because

- the characters are used to create the written representation of the given language
- and the language itself is codified
- each language needs it's "own" characters what allows wrote the language.

After some searching and browsing unicode.org i found that my vague definition

> If you search the web for "pangram" - each author perfectly knows,
>   what characters belongs to his language.

is called as: **minimal characters** required for the language. [Learn more in CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/characters). The definition contains a section `Exemplar Characters`:

> The exemplar character sets contain the commonly used letters for a
>   given modern form of a language.

So, for getting such characters, is enough download the main XML file for the given language, for example:

- http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main/is.xml
- http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main/hu.xml
- http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/browser/trunk/common/main/sk.xml

and extract the: `/ldml/characters/exemplarCharacters`, e.g. such:

for Icelandic

```
<exemplarCharacters>[a á b d ð e é f g h i í j k l m n o ó p r s t u ú v x y ý þ æ ö]</exemplarCharacters>
```

for Slovak

```
<exemplarCharacters>[a á ä b c č d ď e é f g h {ch} i í j k l ĺ ľ m n ň o ó ô p q r ŕ s š t ť u ú v w x y ý z ž]</exemplarCharacters>
```

for Hungarian

```
<exemplarCharacters>[a á b c {cs} {ccs} d {dz} {ddz} {dzs} {ddzs} e é f g {gy} {ggy} h i í j k l {ly} {lly} m n {ny} {nny} o ó ö ő p r s {sz} {ssz} t {ty} {tty} u ú ü ű v z {zs} {zzs}]</exemplarCharacters>
```

And this is *exactly* what I need. Maybe this helps some others too.

### EDIT

Now exists the https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::CLDR module which contains the all needed informations (and much more from the CLDR)

Comment: Congratulations for finding CLDR! I was just going to recommend it. Notice that you get a bunch more information there to in the presented there, including ordering and digraphs (and trigraphs (and tetragraphs)).